# Typescript TS2322 error when using lookup types

Tags: typescript

I'm racking my brain why the following code doesn't compile:

```
interface Circle { type: "circle"; }
interface Rectangle { type: "rectangle"; }
type Shape = Circle | Rectangle;

interface Circle { type: "circle"; }
interface Rectangle { type: "rectangle"; }
type ShapeTemplate = {
  type: Shape["type"];
};

const fromTemplate = (template: ShapeTemplate): Shape => template;
```

It breaks with:

`TS2322: Type 'ShapeTemplate' is not assignable to type 'Shape'. Type 'ShapeTemplate' is not assignable to type 'Rectangle'. Types of property 'type' are incompatible. Type '"circle" | "rectangle"' is not assignable to type '"rectangle"'. Type '"circle"' is not assignable to type '"rectangle"'.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that it is generally too complex for the TypeScript compiler to reduce `{x: A} | {x: B}` to `{x: A|B}`.

You can read about this in the discussion at [Microsoft/TypeScript#7553](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7553) and some other places I can't find right now. (Edit: also see [Microsoft/TypeScript#18230](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18230).) I think the maintainers of the language don't consider it worthwhile to try to implement this, because most of the time it isn't useful in practice; types people really use *generally* have more than one property, and as soon as you have `{x: A, y: P } | {x: B, y: Q}`, a reduction to something like `{x: A|B, y: P|Q}` is not valid.

In practice, the workaround here is to just assert that a `ShapeTemplate` is assignable to `Shape`, like so:

```
const fromTemplate = (template: ShapeTemplate): Shape => template as Shape;
```

Hope that helps; good luck!